# Scraping using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

i am trying to extract one figure from a gov website, I have done a lot of googling and I am kinda lost for ideas, my code below returns a figure but it isnt the figure I want to get and I am not entirely sure why.

I want to subtract the figure from the 'Cases by Area (Whole Pandemic)' table 'Upper tier LA' section and 'Southend on Sea' Case number.

https://coronavirus.data.gov.uk/details/cases

I stole this code from online somewhere and tried to replicate with my class number I found within F12 section on the site.

```
Sub ExtractLastValue()

Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

objIE.Top = 0
objIE.Left = 0
objIE.Width = 800
objIE.Height = 600

objIE.Visible = True

objIE.Navigate ("https://coronavirus.data.gov.uk/details/cases")

Do
DoEvents
Loop Until objIE.readystate = 4

MsgBox objIE.document.getElementsByClassName("sc-bYEvPH khGBIg govuk-table__cell govuk-table__cell--numeric ")(0).innerText

Set objIE = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: This doesn't return a value for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data comes from the official API and returns a json response dynamically on that page when you click the Upper Tier panel.

---

Have a look and play with the API guidance
here:

`https://coronavirus.data.gov.uk/details/developers-guide`

---

You can make a direct xhr request by following the guidance in the API documentation and then  using a json parser to handle the response. For your request it would be something like the following:

```
https://coronavirus.data.gov.uk/api/v1/data?filters=areaName=Southend-on-Sea&areaType=utla&latestBy=cumCasesByPublishDate&structure=
{"date":"date", "areaName":"areaName","cumCasesByPublishDate":"cumCasesByPublishDate",
"cumCasesByPublishDateRate":"cumCasesByPublishDateRate"}
```

---

**XHR:**

A worked example using jsonconverter.bas as the json parser

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GetCovidNumbers()
    Dim http As Object, json As Object

    Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

    With http
        .Open "GET", "https://coronavirus.data.gov.uk/api/v1/data?filters=areaName=Southend-on-Sea&areaType=utla&latestBy=cumCasesByPublishDate&structure={""date"":""date"",""areaName"":""areaName"",""cumCasesByPublishDate"":""cumCasesByPublishDate"",""cumCasesByPublishDateRate"":""cumCasesByPublishDateRate""}", False
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0"
        .send
        Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(.responseText)("data")(1)
    End With
    With ActiveSheet
        Dim arr()
        arr = json.Keys
        .Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, UBound(arr) + 1) = arr
        arr = json.Items
        .Cells(2, 1).Resize(1, UBound(arr) + 1) = arr
    End With
End Sub
```

---

Json library (Used in above solution):

I use jsonconverter.bas. Download raw code from [here](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON/blob/master/JsonConverter.bas) and add to standard module called JsonConverter . You then need to go VBE > Tools > References > Add reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime. Remove the top Attribute line from the copied code.

---

**Internet Explorer:**

You could do a slower, more complicated, internet explorer solution where you need to select the utla option when present, then select from the table the desired value:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GetCovidNumbers()
    'Tools references Microsoft Internet Controls and Microsoft HTML Object Library
    
    Dim ie As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer, t As Date, ele As Object
    Const MAX_WAIT_SEC As Long = 10
    
    Set ie = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    
    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate2 "https://coronavirus.data.gov.uk/details/cases"
        While .Busy Or .ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Wend
        
        t = Timer 'timed loop for element to be present to click on (to get utla)
        Do
            On Error Resume Next
            Set ele = .Document.querySelector("#card-cases_by_area_whole_pandemic [aria-label='Upper tier LA']")
            On Error GoTo 0
            If Timer - t > MAX_WAIT_SEC Then Exit Do
        Loop While ele Is Nothing

        If ele Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
        
        ele.Click
        
        While .Busy Or .ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Wend
        
        Dim table As MSHTML.HTMLTable, datetime As String, result()
        
        Set table = .Document.querySelector("table[download='cumCasesByPublishDate,cumCasesByPublishDateRate']")
        datetime = .Document.querySelector("time").getAttribute("datetime")
        result = GetDataForUtla("Southend-on-Sea", datetime, table)
        
        With ActiveSheet
            .Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, 4) = Array("Datetime", "Area", "Cases", "Rate per 100,000 population")
            .Cells(2, 1).Resize(1, UBound(result) + 1) = result
        End With
        .Quit
    End With
    
End Sub

Public Function GetDataForUtla(ByVal utla As String, ByVal datetime As String, ByVal table As MSHTML.HTMLTable) As Variant
    Dim row As MSHTML.HTMLTableRow, i As Long

    For Each row In table.Rows
        
        If InStr(row.outerHTML, utla) > 0 Then
            Dim arr(4)
            arr(0) = datetime
            For i = 0 To 2
                arr(i + 1) = row.Children(i).innerText
            Next
            GetDataForUtla = arr
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
    GetDataForUtla = Array("Not found")
End Function
```

---

References:

1. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors
2. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector

Comment: Ok dude I really do not understand any of it but it works so there is that... You are a genius.

Comment: Happy to explain further any details you are interested in.

Comment: More than happy if you have the time (and patience). I was trying to see what the arr variable is  but it doesnt show me anything

Comment: I will open a room to discuss it hopefully. Give me a moment.

Comment: Can you enter and chat in here? https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226992/discussion

Comment: It says I need 20 reputation to use that which i unfortunately do not have. I have all other platforms though, well mostly all

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226993/discussion-between-qharr-and-paulr23).

Comment: you can enter the chat above ^^